# Crash in relation to in-app purchasing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have an app just launched on the market which employs in-app purchasing which was cobbled together from other people's example code which I barely understand. The code does appear to work most of the time, but I have one device on which it crashes every time. It appears to crash within some "generated java files" in the gen directory and I traced the last few steps just before the crash as follows:

```
protected static boolean isBillingSupported()
{
    if (amIDead())
    {
        return false;
    }
    Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("CHECK_BILLING_SUPPORTED");

    if (mService != null && request != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);
```

then I step into this method and the following lines get executed... (see comments)

```
public android.os.Bundle sendBillingRequest(android.os.Bundle bundle) throws android.os.RemoteException
{
    android.os.Parcel _data = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
    android.os.Parcel _reply = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
    android.os.Bundle _result;
    try 
    {
        _data.writeInterfaceToken(DESCRIPTOR); // DESCRIPTOR was "com.android.vending.billing.IMarketBillingService"
        if ((bundle!=null))
        {
            _data.writeInt(1); // GOT HERE OK
            bundle.writeToParcel(_data, 0);
        }
        else 
        {
            _data.writeInt(0);
        }
        mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_sendBillingRequest, _data, _reply, 0); // GOT HERE OK
        _reply.readException(); // GOT HERE OK  ... BUT THEN JUMPS TO XXXX
        if ((0!=_reply.readInt())) // WE NEVER REACH THIS LINE!
        {
            _result = android.os.Bundle.CREATOR.createFromParcel(_reply);
        }
        else
        {
            _result = null;
        }
    }
    finally // XXXX
    {
        _reply.recycle(); // THIS GETS EXECUTED
        _data.recycle(); // THIS GETS EXECUTED
    }
    return _result; // WE REACH HERE, BUT THAT'S THE LAST LINE I SEE BEFORE THE EXCEPTION APPEARS IN THE LOG OUTPUT
}
```

The Log file shows the following:

```
01-10 22:54:00.730: W/dalvikvm(1292): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401cb760)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1275)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at com.android.vending.billing.IMarketBillingService$Stub$Proxy.sendBillingRequest(IMarketBillingService.java:100)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at com.mycompany.mygame.BillingHelper.isBillingSupported(BillingHelper.java:64)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at com.mycompany.mygame.Shop.onClick(Shop.java:174)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3122)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11942)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
01-10 22:54:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(1292):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 22:54:02.770: I/dalvikvm(1292): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
01-10 22:54:02.770: I/dalvikvm(1292): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

I'm not sure where to go from here as I am completely confused as to what is going on. I am baffled as to how or why this code even got be be "generated"... presumably even if I saw a bug here I could not edit it anyway! Is this code part of the Android OS? Perhaps the real error is within the passed bundle?.. all hints welcome.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with in app purchase. But hope you've read [the documentation for `readException()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readException()).

Comment: What is line 64 of BillingHelper? and what does the catch around `sendBillingRequest` catch

Comment: You can see from the Logcat trace that line 64 of BillingHelper is `Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request)`. My guess would be is that it catches `android.os.RemoteException`, as is thrown by `sendBillingRequest`

Comment: Which version of Android is the device that crashes running?

Comment: Its a galaxy tab 10.1 running Android 3.1 ... right now I'm getting some different behaviour of my app - just doing some more testing now - will report later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `android.os.Parcel.obtain()` command is returning with null, which would cause the NPE on `_reply.readException()`.

What happens if you try:

```
if ((_reply!=null)) {
    _reply.readException();
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "_reply is null");
}
```

**Edit**

Seeing as that didn't work, I had a little dig around, and found this thread:
http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=25
Which seems to suggest this as an answer:

> This happens when the device has not accepted the License Agreement and try to call this line I encountered this problem when my client just bought a new device and try run my app which make use of inApp so he didnt ever opened market app in his device and so had never accepted the Agreement once you accept the it this error will not be there

Comment: Stepping through with the debugger, I see that _reply is not null. But I can not edit this code because it is automatically generated (I don't know how). The code I included in the question was just temporarily reformatted and had comments added.

Comment: aah, right. Sorry, it didn't click that you'd said it was a gen file

Comment: Hmmm... so this looks like an explanation of what has happened, but its still not very satisfactory that the program crashes :-(

Comment: Well, the program crashes, but only on a development device which hasn't been registered to the market (which, presumably, includes emulators)

Comment: Oh I see. Well that's ok then, you get the tick.